# Running Jre 7 from a Path with Unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, jvm

I'm Having the following errors:

> Error: Registry key Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment.
>   Error: Could not find java.dll.
>   Error: Could not find java SE Runtime Environment.

when I'm running *Jre 7 86x* from a folder that contains *Unicode* characters.

To reproduce this dysfunction follow those steps:

1. Copy *Jre 7 86x* folder to a folder in which it's name contains Unicode characters for example (*功能障碍*).
2. Try to execute *java.exe* / *javaw.exe*.

**The system language must be different from any Unicode language (Chinese, Japanese, ...), in my case the system language is English.**

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Maybe related to: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4488646

Comment: it could be, i'm not quite sure. and if this is my problem, is there anyway to avoid it without renaming the folder.

Comment: Did you install the JRE into this folder, or did you copy it?  The windows installer creates the initial path.  ie. RuntimeLib is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\server\jvm.dll on my installation.  I would think if you copied the JVM, you can go into regedit and modify the path, so it knows where to find it.

Comment: Yes, it's a copy. But, i don't think this problem have a relation with the the Jre identification in the registry. Because, if I create another copy, but in a folder in which it's name doesn't contain any Unicode characters it would work correctly.

Comment: @AnnabiGihed Windows neds to find the DLL's somehow, either they are in your current directory, or it is defined for your user in the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables.  If that's the case, you could change your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables in windows or where ever you define them.  If your having an issue with the unicode characters, you could always find the short name for the unicode directory by doing a dir/x at the command line and use the short name in your PATH / JAVA_HOME.